# I need to nullify (not to counter) effect of parent CSS file

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-float

First of all, I am working on "rtl" directional web pages. 
And, I am using bootstrap component called "breadcrumbs", in my shop.html template. Therefore, I want my breadcrumbs in right to left direction.

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <div class="container" align="right">
        <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="{% url 'bookrepo:home' %}">صفحہ اول</a>
        <span class="breadcrumb-item active"> خریداری </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have made my own shop.css file for cutomized styling. Now, issue is that though I have done `align:"right"` in my template.

But parent file of bootstrap overriding its placement to left. By (https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/scss/_breadcrumb.scss):

```
.breadcrumb-item {
float: left;
}
```

So, it is like that now:
[image: Effects due to parent bootstrap css]

Where I want it to float:right. So what I did in my shop.css is that:

```
.breadcrumb-item {
float: right;
}
```

But it didn't go according to plan. It is ruining orientation of breadcrumb. Have a look at it:
[image: Effects of overriding in my shop.css]

So, it means I don't want it to float in neither direction. When I un-apply both it works fine.

Have a look at it:

[image: Both effects unapplied]

Obviously, I can erase `float:right` from my shop.css. So, now guide me to the way to nullify bootstrap's css effect which is `float:left`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear the float

```css
.breadcrumb-item {
clear:both;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate that but It is ruining orientation by expanding both items in different lines.